# mysql removing duplicates with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

i am trying to remove duplicate records having same `hid` values.

Here's the Fiddle:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=86e8ed00cf0a496da490eae5d7aae093

Table product_match_unmatches:

```
ID  hid flag
1   1   1
2   1   1
3   2   1
4   2   1
5   1   2
6   2   2
7   2   2
8   1   1
9   1   1
10  2   1
```

Now I want to remove duplicates `hid` from the table but for flag = 1 only.

This query will remove all `duplicates` except for the recent one, but irrespective of flag values:

```
DELETE pmu1
FROM dmf_product_match_unmatches as pmu1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT MAX(ID) as ID, hid
            FROM dmf_product_match_unmatches as pmu2
            GROUP BY hid) pmu3 USING (ID, hid)
WHERE pmu3.ID IS NULL;
```

I tried to add where clause `flag = 1` in the above query but this is not producing desired result.

```
DELETE pmu1
FROM dmf_product_match_unmatches as pmu1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT MAX(ID) as ID, hid
            FROM dmf_product_match_unmatches as pmu2
            where flag = 1
            GROUP BY hid
          ) pmu3 USING (ID, hid)
WHERE pmu3.ID IS NOT NULL;
```

The required output is:

```
ID  hid flag
5   1   2
6   2   2
7   2   2
9   1   1
10  2   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need in

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM dmf_product_match_unmatches t1
JOIN dmf_product_match_unmatches t2 USING (hid, flag)
WHERE flag = 1 
  AND t1.id < t2.id;
```

?

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a5e9e95335573ebedd45cdcd577b5602

Comment: very smart but what happens if table is very large? the joined records will explode?

Comment: *what happens if table is very large?* ?? The amount of removed rows from large table is greater than one from small table (in general, of course). *the joined records will explode?* I cannot understend what do you mean.

Comment: if you have many duplicates, this join, with that where condition, will produce a result set with many rows. In the example the selected rows will be 9 instead of 5 with 4 duplicates because the join will tie each row to all other similar and the where will filter only a few, if you add (11, 1, 1) you will get 13 rows instead of 6 and so on.. ok, no effect on the delete, but maybe effect on the performance of selection. I'm not sure if optimizer will auto use something like a distinct clause. I was just asking.

Comment: *if you have many duplicates, this join, with that where condition, will produce a result set with many rows.* Your words are correct for SELECT, but UPDATE / DELETE works by another way, which is close to WHERE EXISTS pre-selection. The aim of this pre-selection is to mark the rows for deletion.

Answer (score 1):

Using `row_number`

```
DELETE pmu1
FROM dmf_product_match_unmatches pmu1
JOIN (select id,
         row_number() over(partition by hid order by id desc) rn
       from dmf_product_match_unmatches 
       where flag = 1
     ) as pmu3 ON pmu1.ID = pmu3.ID
WHERE pmu3.rn > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In sql server you can use the `EXCEPT` set operator:

```
declare @flag int = 1

delete dmf_product_match_unmatches
where id in (

    select id
    from dmf_product_match_unmatches
    where flag = @flag

    except

    select max(id) id
    from dmf_product_match_unmatches
    where flag = @flag
    group by hid, flag
)
```

In mysql you can use `NOT EXISTS`

```
declare @flag int = 1

delete d1
from dmf_product_match_unmatches d1
where flag = @flag
and not exists (
    select max(id) id
    from dmf_product_match_unmatches  d2
    group by hid, flag
    having d1.id = max(d2.id)       
)
```